# Weird BinaryFormatter deseralization error in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter, msgpack

I am encountering a really weird Exception on one of my application (later referenced as **ApplicationB**)

```
`Unable to find assembly 'MsgPack, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a2625990d5dc0167'.`
```

Here is my scenario, on my **ApplicationA** I have serialized an object using MsgPack and store it into Redis using SE.Redis. Later on, I query this object and deserialize it (of course still using MsgPack). Once this is done, I am sending this object via a TCP/Componennt that serializes this same object using BinaryFormatter. On the other side, ie on **ApplicationB**, once the packet arrived, it is deserialized using BinaryFormatter and this is where I get the exception.

I don't have any control on the TCP/Component and the serializer it uses.

So why do I get this error on **ApplicationB** which should know any thing about MsgPack?

Just a thought I want to share, it seems that MsgPack create on the fly DataContract and when deserializing, it might applies some attributes on the object that conflict with the BinaryFormatter. Of course I am not sure about that.

But has anyone encountered this problem?

Cheers.

EDIT: I noticed that for member of type object, MsgPack adds a lot of members for defining the type store in the object member (like IsDictionary, IsList, etc.). Does it impact BinaryFormatter?

Comment: It is a simple "file not found" error.  With the most obvious cause that MsgPack.dll is not present in ApplicationB's probing path.  Or it has the wrong version.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: I don't need MsgPack.dll on **ApplicationB** and it should not even know about MsgPack.

Comment: Well, of course you do.  It is yelling at you loudly.

Comment: But why does **ApplicationB** need this DLL?

Answer (score 3):

When using binary serialization, only the fully qualified type name and its data is serialized to a byte-array. The serializer on the other side wants to deserialize its data. It first reads the type name from the byte-array and tries to find and instanciate that type. That type must be somewhere in a DLL. So it looks for the given DLL (in your case `MsgPack`) but it cannot be found. Thus: Make sure the DLL `MsgPack` is located on both sides.

If it is not possible to to have the DLL on the other side, your could try to serialize the DLL itself and send it over to the other side. First deserialize the DLL, put it inside your bin folder or load it into memory, then deserialize the type with its data. But you must really, really, really make sure if you wanna do that. I wouldn't.

Have you ever considered communicating between AppA en AppB using WCF?